# Unable to create a build with version number in mac using pyinstaller

Tags: python, macos, version, pyinstaller

I have been trying to create a cross platform application using python
Now am trying to build the same using pyintaller. In windows I got an option like

```
pyintaller <name_of_python_file> --onefile --noconsole --version-file = version.txt
```

But this optin doesn't work for mac.(They have mentioned it in the documentation)

So is there any other option by which i can set version to my build in mac?

Or is there any option other than pyinstaller to create build for mac

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

1. "--nocnsole" is incorrect - please check your spelling..
2. "--version-File" is also incorrect - please check your capitalization.

   - I suspect that this particular option is not supported with Mac Bundles. Consider editing the generated .App instead.

In general, when asking for help on a programming or dev-oriented website, try to reproduce your problem in a few short lines.

Then *cut and paste* that example into your question.

Explain clearly what happens, and what you expected to happen.

Comment: Thanks, @Arafangion. The errors you pointed out were just typos happened while typing directly instead of copy pasting. Will consider your suggestions on my further activities.